# Windows 10 killed ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, installation, arcgis-10.5, windows-10

I’m hoping to find a solution. I’m running Windows 10 on a Dell XPS, and I have a single install license of ArcMap 10.5. The Windows 10 fall 2017 Creators Update has killed ArcGIS Desktop. It can’t open after installing this update. However, ArcCatalog runs without any trouble.

I’d love any troubleshooting suggestions. I can run Desktop for a while after I roll back the Windows update, but since I can’t disable Windows updates it’s short lived, because ArcGIS Desktop starts crashing as soon as the update downloads.

Update: I checked in my license, uninstalled Arc, rebooted, reinstalled Arc, re-checked out my license, and Desktop still can't open.  ArcCatalog still runs with no trouble.

Comment: try uninstalling and reinstalling ArcGIS Desktop after the update.

Comment: @Dowlers, I would try that but the single-use license will terminate if I uninstall. Unfortunately my employer doesn't have the resources to buy another license right now.

Comment: @Mechanism Sounds like you need to talk to Esri, "the single-use license will terminate if I uninstall" is a new one to me. If your employer paid for a license at some point and you've lost your license key or whatever, Esri support can get it for you.

Comment: If you have the key you should be able to check back in the license. Maybe check to see if that is the case, but I have de-activated, then re-activated the same key after re-install. I think you can only do that a couple times. I had to call ESRI support once to reset it.

Comment: @Mechanism As other have said you can first Deauthorize the license using ArcGIS Administrator and then reautherize again after the reinstall.

Comment: Ugh, thank you! In my immense frustration I forgot all about checking in the license. I’ll give it a try 

Comment: Thanks, everybody. Checking in the license worked. Unfortunately, reinstalling ArcMap did not fix my problem. Desktop still crashes as it attempts to load.

Comment: I am getting the same problem please help me to sol"ArcMap has stopped working - A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

Answer (score 1):

call ESRI Support, they will provide your license key for you if you need to re-install and do not have it on-hand. But before uninstalling I would attempt a **Repair Install** and see if the files were moved, replaced by the updates.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately the Repair Install is the first thing I tried, and it didn’t work.

Comment: what error are you seeing when you try to open ArcMap?

Comment: "ArcMap has stopped working  - A problem caused the program to stop working correctly. Windows will close the program and notify you if a solution is available."

Answer (score 1):

Since the License Manager and Desktop are installed separately, I guess you could try to reinstall ArcGIS Desktop without messing your License Manager installation.